# Subbottom giving weird errors when I use captions for my subfigures

Tags: floats, captions, memoir, subfloats

I have a figure with the following syntax:

```
\begin{figure}[h!] \centering
\subbottom[$H_n = A_n / e$]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=defnode]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subbottom[$S_n = A_n - e$]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=defnode]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
```

But when I try to compile I get the two following errors:

```
undefined control sequence {
```

and

```
undefined control sequence \end{figure}
```

pointing at the last two lines of my figure. These do not make much sense to me. If I try to remove the caption [..] of my subbottoms, I do not get this mistake.

I have included `\usepackage{subfig}` in a `memoir` document.

This is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,showtrims,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % danske tegn

\usepackage{./memfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig}
\tikzstyle{defnode}=[circle,fill=white,draw=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]\centering
\subbottom[$F_n$]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=defnode]
\draw (0,0) node(a) {};
\draw (2.2,1) node(b1) {};
\draw (2.5,0.5) node(b2) {};
\draw (2.6,0) node(b3) {};
\draw (2.5,-0.5) node(b4) {};
\draw (2.2,-1) node(b5) {};
\draw (a) to (b1);
\draw (a) to (b2);
\draw (a) to (b3);
\draw (a) to (b4);
\draw (a) to (b5);
\draw (b1) to (b2) to (b3) to (b4) to (b5);
\end{tikzpicture}
} \hspace{1cm}
\subbottom[$G_n$]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=defnode]
\draw (0,0) node(a) {};
\draw (2.2,1) node(b1) {};
\draw (2.5,0.5) node(b2) {};
\draw (2.6,0) node(b3) {};
\draw (2.5,-0.5) node(b4) {};
\draw (2.2,-1) node(b5) {};
\draw (a) [bend left=10] to (b1);
\draw (a) [bend right=10] to (b1);
\draw (a) to (b2);
\draw (a) to (b3);
\draw (a) to (b4);
\draw (a) to (b5);
\draw (b1) to (b2) to (b3) to (b4) to (b5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's difficult to say without a minimum working example (MWE). Would you mind preparing one that illustrates the issue, and we can try to help? See this discussion if you're unsure what MWE is: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Done, it is now in the question.

Comment: Is there anything important in `memfonts.sty`?

Comment: You should be able to leave it out, but it will give a warning.

Comment: No need for subfig, just add `\newsubfloat{figure}` to preamble as per manual (I'd better add a comment on the page that describes `\subbottom` that one need to define it before use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to use `subfig` package together with `memoir`. Now, `subfig` loads the `caption` package, which `memoir` doesn't seem to like -- it even throws a warning in the output saying exactly that:

```
You are using the caption package with the memoir 
class. This may cause unexpected or inconsistent 
results if you use any of memoir's captioning facilities.
```

The easiest solution probably would be to replace the `\subbottom` (from the `ccaption` package loaded by `memoir`) with `\subfloat` and be done about it... Unless you need some of the more advanced functionality `ccaption` provides (bilingual captions, legends, custom caption styles and whatnot).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,showtrims,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % danske tegn

%\usepackage{./memfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig}
\tikzstyle{defnode}=[circle,fill=white,draw=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering

\subfloat[$F_n$]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=defnode]
\draw (0,0) node(a) {};
\draw (2.2,1) node(b1) {};
\draw (2.5,0.5) node(b2) {};
\draw (2.6,0) node(b3) {};
\draw (2.5,-0.5) node(b4) {};
\draw (2.2,-1) node(b5) {};
\draw (a) to (b1);
\draw (a) to (b2);
\draw (a) to (b3);
\draw (a) to (b4);
\draw (a) to (b5);
\draw (b1) to (b2) to (b3) to (b4) to (b5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\hspace{1cm}
\subfloat[$G_n$]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=defnode]
\draw (0,0) node(a) {};
\draw (2.2,1) node(b1) {};
\draw (2.5,0.5) node(b2) {};
\draw (2.6,0) node(b3) {};
\draw (2.5,-0.5) node(b4) {};
\draw (2.2,-1) node(b5) {};
\draw (a) [bend left=10] to (b1);
\draw (a) [bend right=10] to (b1);
\draw (a) to (b2);
\draw (a) to (b3);
\draw (a) to (b4);
\draw (a) to (b5);
\draw (b1) to (b2) to (b3) to (b4) to (b5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Besides, `\subbottom` is used (AFAIR) for providing a caption to a piece of text that can be tracked as a float. I'm not sure you can use it for captioning non-text stuff.